# PDO select with limit returns nothing

Tags: select, pdo, limit

I'm using a select clause with limit to fetch random recodrs from DB but the result is nothing

```
$zero = '0';
$nums = $_REQUEST['nums'];
$stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT Card_Code FROM new_cards WHERE Cat_ID = :cat ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT :startfrom,:nums");
$stmt->bindParam(':cat',$cat,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':startfrom',$zero,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':nums',$nums,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo $row['Card_Code']." - ";
}
```

But if I type in 0 and $nums in the query it works but the bindParam doesn't return any result at all.
Thanks

Comment: You have to bind LIMIT parameters as `PDO::PARAM_INT`.

Comment: Not working code updated please review

Comment: What error message do you get? Try casting the values to an integer properly: `$stmt->bindParam(':startfrom', (int) $zero, PDO::PARAM_INT);`.